# Which type of assembler jump instruction is most useful?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, low-level

I am working on a hobby project to design a small CPU and a microcomputer system around it. I have a basic dataflow and have made some decisions about wordsize and the number of instructions in the ISA. I have decided on a 16-bit word with a 4-bit opcode field. This allows for 16 instructions.

EDIT : 
Some additional information

The instruction word, 16-bit, is formatted as follows :
OOOOPPPPPPPPPPPP

O-bits are opcode, P-bits are the payload, address/data. This allows for 4096 kilowords of address space and 16 opcodes. The restriction to 16 opcodes is a design decision to make the hardware implementation easier.

The architecture has one accumulator (A-register), a B-register and a stack pointer.

/ENDEDIT

The ISA has move and load instructions(Load/store), basic arithmetic and logic (add, sub, NAND), basic stack functions (push and pop). There is also a subroutine (unconditional) jump/return pair of instructions. With all this there is still one piece missing : conditional jumps.

The return function can be the same as for unconditional jump, so what I need is a test of some kind and a jump on condition of that test.

**So, here is my question : what is the most USEFUL kind of test/conditional pair to have?**

There is room for ONE test and ONE conditional jump left in the opcode table, or TWO conditional jumps if you somehow include the condition test in other operations, like ADD or SUB.

Jump on overflow, not Zero, Zero, carry, not carry are some of my ideas, but I am unsure which one(s) would be more useful. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: But what is the size of your instructions ? Usually there are additional fields in the instruction after the opcode. If your instructions are 16-bit, you could have a single 'conditional jump' instruction with an additional 4-bit condition type parameter, and still have 8-bit left for the operands. If this doesn't fit your model, then add more details.

Comment: 4 bits. The word is 16 bits, 4 MSB are the opcode, the 12LSB are data or an address, or in some cases just empty. Sure, I can do 5-bit opcodes, but that limits my address/data payload size. Smaller address size, less memory space available. Each word is one instruction.

Comment: So I take it that you have fixed-size 16-bit instructions. What I was saying is that you could keep your 4-bit opcode, with a 4-bit parameter for condition type in the case of a jump instruction. This gives you a 8-bit relative offset to jump (i.e a relative near jump), but you keep 12-bit operand for other instructions. Do you have any constraint about that ? Also, I'm just curious, but it sounds like your model have a single working register ?

Comment: You can easily emulate push/pop no need to waste opcodes for them if you don't have enough. Same goes for call.

Comment: You made me think of [OISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer).

Comment: @ElderBug, Two registers, an accumulator and a B-register and a  stack pointer.@Jester Yes, you can do a lot with pseudoinstructions, but I prefer builtins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I've been coding assembler for 40+ years; actually designed and built a production multi-register 16 bit machine back in the early 1970s). What would be really useful is a CMP instruction, and a JMP relative that specifies that condition.

I suggest you let the arithmetic instructions produce status bits for

- Zero result
- Carry from result
- Sign of result
- (Signed) Overflow

We'll call these "condition bits".  You'll discover they are all pretty useful.

Your compare instruction should basically do a subtract, and throw the answer away, setting the condition bits.

Your JMP instruction should use one of the 16 opcodes, a 3 bit condition-selector, and a 9 bit relative offset from the PC, e.g., a jump-relative-conditional to the PC.  Short relative branches are really useful in code.

The 3 bit condition selector should use two bits to select one of the 4 conditions, and one bit to select "invert". This way you can have "jmp zero", "jmp not zero", etc.

You might treat "jump no overflow" instead as "jump always"; these a very handy in code.  (I don't understand how you think "jmp unconditional" and "return from subroutine" can be the same instruction).

From comments in the discussion, it seem you don't have any registers.  That's a serious mistake from the point of view of code compactness (esp. with 16 bit instructions), and performance (registers are invariably faster to access than memory).   I'd use 2 or 3 or the 12 bits left over after the opcode to name registers.

Aha: in an edit, OP notes he has A and B registers, probably selected implicitly by opcode.  The machine I designed was inspired by the PDP-11, but had 16 base opcodes with *8* registers (leaving 9 bits of "operand") and it really made a difference in coding. Most of the instructions broke those 9 bits into addressing modes and offsets: direct (uses a 2nd word as the address), immediate (2nd word), immediate (7 bits, meant the machine could process ASCII text easily), indirect 2nd register auto-increment, indirect 2nd register auto decrement, short-offset relative to 2nd register, and 2nd-word offset relative to register.  It did not have a stack, but you can implement one trivially using the auto-inc/decrement instructions so no loss.
It was a pleasure to code for. (It also had virtual memory with traps, and a hardware context switch between register sets and VM mappings).

While all this sounds like it requires complex logic to decode, it does not.
We managed to implement this machine with ~~ 120 so-called "medium scale" chips (4 gates per chip, multiplexors, 4 bit adder slice, etc.).   These days I'd expect you to be able to implement the whole thing in a single FPGA.

Comment: Thank you,  thats very useful information. PC-relative jumping, hadnt thought of that. As for this : _italic_(I don't understand how you think "jmp unconditional" and "return from subroutine" can be the same instruction)._italic_ I just meant that a return is a return no matter why you originally jumped.

Comment: An unconditional branch doesn't produce a "reason to return", so what would the "return instruction" do in that case?

Comment: SImple rule:  when designing an instruction set, make sure you have looked a lot of other ones.  People do surprisingly interesting things.

Comment: A terminology mixup, my bad. GOTO and GOSUB arent the same thing, Im gonna go write that on the blackboard a few hundred times.

Comment: Ive been reading through the Z80 instruction set, the 4004, the SAP-1, TM-16, PDP-variants, LC-3, MARIE, 6502, 8080, and a few others. Some of it better documented than others. The architecture is based on the SAP-1 by Malvino but with a few added bits and bobs to make it more useful (in my eyes at least).

Comment: @Psvedman SAP-1 is terrible choice to base your instruction set on. It's not even Turing complete. It's just a toy. A better example would be the  AVR instruction set. It's a real, practical and successful architecture. It's also relatively modern and so it incorporates lessons learned from previous architectures.

Comment: I agree, SAP-1 is terrible as it is defined in the literature, but as a learning tool its pretty great. Its small enough to grok and easily expandable. I have added all the parts needed to make it Turing complete and able to execute any algorithm (given RAM enough). This question is about which kind of conditional branching instructions are most useful, if I have to choose one or possibly two.

Comment: @Psvedman: At the complete other end of the spectrum of hardware complexity, a variable-length instruction set can give high code density while still allowing lots of opcodes and large immediates.  An "escape sequence" opcode acts as a modifier for the next opcode.  Anyway, not that you'd want to implement anything like this, but [Agner Fog's recent blog post proposing an instruction-set for high-performance computing.](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=421#470) has some isn set ideas.  He tries to keep some of what's good about x86 while dropping the bad.

Answer (score 0):

With two opcodes left, one test and one conditional jump instruction as you suggested is a good idea.

If you want to keep the 4/12 opcode/operand format, you could put the condition in the TEST, and have the JMP instruction jump if the TEST yield true. You would then have a 12-bit field just to select the test type. In this field you could encode anything you want : `A is 0`, `A is not 0`, `A > 0`, `A < B`, `A + B overflow` ... Note that complex comparisons become a bit awkward, because they would mean that TEST can do more complex operations than any other instructions, but the whole set of simple comparisons still makes sense.

Example :

```
LOAD_A [0x30]
LOAD_B [0x40]
TEST (SIGNED A < B)
JIF MY_ADDRESS
```

The jumps can be absolute 12-bit or relative 12-bit. Many simple ISA implements relative address because they are smaller, but absolute ones are simpler to assemble (if you write the program by hand, you are less likely to change addresses every time you change the program).